# Simplest way to get Class.getResource()to use current ThreadContext class loader

Tags: java, classloader

It would seem that Class.getResource() uses the Class class loader and ignores the Thread context class loader which is not what i want. Any tipson how toget around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was tehe result of a bad classloader where my class loader did not override getResourceAsStream(). Once that was implemented things just work :)

I ended up overriding ObjectInputStream.readResolve() to use a provider that is passed to the ctor.

thankx all

Answer (score 1):

Just go and get the current thread class loader and run the getResource on it:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "path-to-resource.here" );
```

Comment: Thats exactly what im trying to avoid because it means my code now needs to know when to check if a context class loader or default to the regular way.